# Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema, order mixed up

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to implement this database with quite a few parameters. Unfortunately I cannot figure out why the order is mixed up that badly. The database is being read from the assets, it's already populated with ~250 items.

**Error Message:**

```
Expected:                                                                                     
TableInfo{name='Item', columns={tradingItem3Amount=Column{name='tradingItem3Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting2Amount=Column{name='itemCrafting2Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting4Amount=Column{name='itemCrafting4Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, buoyancy=Column{name='buoyancy', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ItemCategory=Column{name='ItemCategory', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem1Amount=Column{name='tradingItem1Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting3=Column{name='itemCrafting3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting4=Column{name='itemCrafting4', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting1=Column{name='itemCrafting1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting2=Column{name='itemCrafting2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCraftingAmount=Column{name='itemCraftingAmount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, durability=Column{name='durability', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, weight=Column{name='weight', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, friction=Column{name='friction', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting3Amount=Column{name='itemCrafting3Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, imgUrl=Column{name='imgUrl', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem1=Column{name='tradingItem1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem2=Column{name='tradingItem2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem3=Column{name='tradingItem3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, flammable=Column{name='flammable', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting1Amount=Column{name='itemCrafting1Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem2Amount=Column{name='tradingItem2Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, modpack=Column{name='modpack', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, extraInfo=Column{name='extraInfo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingAmount=Column{name='tradingAmount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

                                                                         
Found:
TableInfo{name='Item', columns={Category=Column{name='Category', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, Description=Column{name='Description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem3Amount=Column{name='tradingItem3Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, Name=Column{name='Name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem1Amount=Column{name='tradingItem1Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting3=Column{name='itemCrafting3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting4=Column{name='itemCrafting4', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting1=Column{name='itemCrafting1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCrafting2=Column{name='itemCrafting2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCraftingAmount=Column{name='itemCraftingAmount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, itemCraftingAmount1=Column{name='itemCraftingAmount1', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCraftingAmount2=Column{name='itemCraftingAmount2', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCraftingAmount3=Column{name='itemCraftingAmount3', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, itemCraftingAmount4=Column{name='itemCraftingAmount4', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, Durability=Column{name='Durability', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, Flammable=Column{name='Flammable', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, Bouyancy=Column{name='Bouyancy', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ItemID=Column{name='ItemID', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, Weight=Column{name='Weight', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem1=Column{name='tradingItem1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem2=Column{name='tradingItem2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem3=Column{name='tradingItem3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, Friction=Column{name='Friction', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingItem2Amount=Column{name='tradingItem2Amount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, modpack=Column{name='modpack', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, extraInfo=Column{name='extraInfo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, tradingAmount=Column{name='tradingAmount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

**The create statement:**

This statement is copied from [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

```
CREATE TABLE "Item" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "Name"  TEXT,
    "ItemID"    TEXT,
    "Category"  TEXT,
    "Description"   TEXT,
    "Weight"    INTEGER,
    "Durability"    INTEGER,
    "Friction"  INTEGER,
    "Bouyancy"  INTEGER,
    "Flammable" INTEGER,
    "itemCrafting1" TEXT,
    "itemCraftingAmount1"   INTEGER,
    "itemCrafting2" TEXT,
    "itemCraftingAmount2"   INTEGER,
    "itemCrafting3" TEXT,
    "itemCraftingAmount3"   INTEGER,
    "itemCrafting4" TEXT,
    "itemCraftingAmount4"   INTEGER,
    "extraInfo" TEXT,
    "itemCraftingAmount"    INTEGER,
    "tradingAmount" INTEGER,
    "tradingItem1"  TEXT,
    "tradingItem1Amount"    INTEGER,
    "tradingItem2"  TEXT,
    "tradingItem2Amount"    INTEGER,
    "tradingItem3"  TEXT,
    "tradingItem3Amount"    INTEGER,
    "modpack"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
)
```

**Item.kt**

```
package com.blazecode.scrapguidev2.ui.items

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import com.blazecode.scrapguidev2.ui.items.enums.Modpack
import com.blazecode.scrapguidev2.ui.items.enums.ItemCategory

@Entity
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey var id: String = "0",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imgUrl") var imgUrl: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ItemCategory") var category: ItemCategory?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "weight") var weight: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "durability") var durability: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "friction") var friction: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "buoyancy") var buoyancy: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "flammable") var flammable: Boolean?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting1") var itemCrafting1: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting2") var itemCrafting2: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting3") var itemCrafting3: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting4") var itemCrafting4: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting1Amount") var itemCrafting1Amount: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting2Amount") var itemCrafting2Amount: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting3Amount") var itemCrafting3Amount: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCrafting4Amount") var itemCrafting4Amount: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "extraInfo") var extraInfo: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemCraftingAmount") var itemCraftingAmount: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tradingAmount") var tradingAmount: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tradingItem1") var tradingItem1: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tradingItem1Amount") var tradingItem1Amount: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tradingItem2") var tradingItem2: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tradingItem2Amount") var tradingItem2Amount: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tradingItem3") var tradingItem3: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tradingItem3Amount") var tradingItem3Amount: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "modpack") var modpack: Modpack?
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is irrelevant, it is not an issue. From a very quick inspection (of the generated SQL - see below) you have an issue with NOT NULL being omitted for the **id** column. However as explained below comparison/adjustment isn't required as Room generates the **exact SQL** for the table(s).

The simple way to ascertain what Room expects (demands in reality) is to

1. Make the required changes to the `@Entity` annotated classes.
2. Include the `@Entity` annotated classes in the `@Database` annotated class.
3. Compile the project (CTRL + F9)
4. Using the **Android View** of Android Studio go to the java(generated) and expand it to locate the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **_Impl**.
5. Locate the `createAllTables` method and you will see the **exact SQL** for the creation of the table(s).

   1. Ignore the room_master_table Room will ensure that this is created and populated.

The following is an example where your code has been added to an existing project (used for other answers):-

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is by far the best way to debug this issue. I haven't seen that before.